# React native json response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am trying to print json responce in via console.log ,below is my json response but i want each element to print one by one like user.id or product.name

```
    {
    "user": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "User 1"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "User 2"
    }],
    "user_pictures": false,
    "products": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test abc"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test abc 1"
    }],
    "purpose": ""
}
```

I am trying like this:

```
responseData.map((item)=>{
                console.log(item.user.id)
            })
```

but error is show in console

```
TypeError: responseData.map is not a function
```

responseData is the response in json when i call my fetch method

Comment: `.map` only can be use on array, it should be `responseData.user.map({})`

Comment: So maybe first `JSON.parse(responseData)`? How do you request this data? E.g. in jQuery you have to set `dataType: 'json'` for response to be actual json and not string

Answer (score 0):

You can access `id` like this `input.user[0].id`.

Below is working code:

```js
let input = {
    "user": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "User 1"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "User 2"
    }],
    "user_pictures": false,
    "products": [{
        "id": "1",
        "name": "test abc"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "test abc 1"
    }],
    "purpose": ""
};
console.log(input.user[0].id);
```

Answer (score 0):

responseData is an object... you cant map over an object... responseData has 4 properties... users, user_pictures, products, purpose... of which, `responseData.users` and `responseData.products` are arrays that can be mapped over.  user_pictures is a boolean and purpose is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Its Works like this:

```
JSON.parse(responseData).user.map((item)=>{
                console.log(item.id)
            })
```

Thank guys